# Hardware set (machine) for Linux noob in 2020

Tags: laptop, linux, displays

Should I go for old mac air or similarly priced laptops to run Linux as the sole OS on it? **Longevity** of the hardware is a concern and screen viewing should be very pleasant to the eyes (=for **less eye strain**) A few models for comparison “Asus Tuf Gaming FX705DT" and “Asus ZenBook Flip-Ryzen 7" with "MacBook air old model with dual core i5". Will the non mac hardware **last** 7-8 years? Will the mac with Linux **last** 7-8 years? Do you advise me to go for **any other hardware set** which will be **better** than these? Do you advise me to go for the cheapest piece of hardware that supports Linux? N.B. Max $1000 if hardware lasts 7-8 years without problems, otherwise cheap and long lasting is best. Thank you in advance.